# Chrome extension: How to sendMessage form background to background?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

My background listener is

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse)
```

In `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` listener, I want to use the message system,I call

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
```

in the listener, but it's not works.

So, how can I sendMessage from background to background ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Messages dispatched by a page are not received by the same page.

If you want to be able to re-use the `onMessage` listener, put it in a separate function. For example:

```
function alwaysDoSomething() {
    console.log('Done something!');
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    alwaysDoSomething();
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    alwaysDoSomething();
});
```

There is an undocumented method that can be used to manually trigger the events. **It is undocumented, so use it at your own risk**!

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    var message = 'whatever';
    var sender = {tab: null, id: chrome.runtime.id};
    var sendResponse = function() {};
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.dispatch(message, sender, sendResponse);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the only way I can achieve my target.Actually, for every message I have a function to do the thing,the function need the same parameter as the listener.If I call the function directly, it complex my structure.

Comment: @wener The cleanest way to do it is posted on top of my answer, a method that doesn't require any change of your code is posted at the end.

Comment: Thanks, it's looks weird, but I don't have another choose.Maybe this is the missed thing in the extension system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `chrome.extension.onRequestExternal` or `chrome.extension.onConnectExternal`

Comment: I have to make sure the listener can listen the message from contentScript and popup, now the contentScript and popup is works fine, but in background it's not work.