# Chrome Extension - send message from Background to Background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to send a `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the background and catch it in the background.

I did the follow in the `background.js` -

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageListener);

function messageListener (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    switch (request.action) {
        case "backgroundEvent1":
            console.log("backgroundEvent1"); // Not appear
            break;
    }
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "backgroundEvent1" });
```

How could I send the message in the backround and catch it in the background again ?

(PS - I already know about other ways other then `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: How to sendMessage form background to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899769/chrome-extension-how-to-sendmessage-form-background-to-background)